# Google Cloud Firewall: Port is blocked

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, firewall

I am trying to set up a simple web server in Google Cloud Platform on a Debian machine.
When running a port scan (https://www.ipvoid.com/port-scan/) without any firewall rules, all ports are shown as filtered. When setting up a rule for port 80, the scan gives back that the port is blocked. Am I doing something wrong with the firewall settings?

[image: This is what the config looks like.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can paste an english screenshot, it will be easier!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-built your issue on my Gcloud console, 80 port will be blocked if I don't select the firewall options as picture during creating an instance.

[image]

The firewall rule will auto set up if I select these firewall options.
[image]

You also can verify your firewall settings in Debian, View the full list of application profiles by running:

```
$ sudo ufw app list
```

The WWW profiles are used to manage ports used by web servers:

Output

```
Available applications:
. . .
  WWW
  WWW Cache
  WWW Full
  WWW Secure
. . .
```

If you inspect the WWW Full profile, it shows that it enables traffic to ports 80 and 443:

```
$ sudo ufw app info "WWW Full"
```

Output

```
Profile: WWW Full
Title: Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
Description: Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)

Ports:
  80,443/tcp
```

Allow incoming HTTP and HTTPS traffic for this profile:

```
$sudo ufw allow in "WWW Full"
```

Comment: Thanks! The http and https rules were indeed removed when I removed all firewall rules. I tried to set it up like you, but it still doesn't work: https://photos.app.goo.gl/C94DiSFwkWducLeD6

Comment: I checked the photos which you shared, it shows the port 80 is closed, it's not filtered, could you make sure that the Web service is on ?

Comment: Thanks! The web service was indeed not running :)